# Apple Itunes app limitations

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a iPhone game that I am creating and wanted to know a couple limitations

- once the person downloads the game and they sign in with a user name I want them to be able to download new content maps packs etc. What is the limit in size these downloads can be?
- where can this content be stored?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the max size of your app is 2GB.

As for storing content:

> For security purposes, an application has only a few locations in which it can write its data and preferences. When an application is installed on a device, a home directory is created for the application. Table 6-1 lists some of the important subdirectories inside the home directory that you might need to access. This table describes the intended usage and access restrictions for each directory and whether the directory’s contents are backed up by iTunes. For more information about the backup and restore process, see “Backup and Restore.” For more information about the application home directory itself, see “The Application Sandbox.”

Source and Table 6-1: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html

Comment: The link above has changed. Here is the new link (scroll down to the "File System" heading): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html

Answer (score 0):

The download limits are based on the network they are attached to and may be different in different markets.  Over 3G the limit is now 20MB it used to be 20MB IIRC.  There is no cap over wifi or directly syncing via iTunes.